# Match Names on Two Sheets, return True or False

Tags: excel, formula

Spent a long time searching hoping to find this, but everything I see is trying to fetch other data with VLOOKUP. Since I just need a count of matches, I just need it to return True or False.

Two Sheets named 'X' and 'Y'. Trying to match Column A "FirstName" and Column B "Last Name"

For example, if someone on Sheet B is name John Smith, I need to see if someone on Sheet A is also named John Smith (with both names being on the same row). If so, return true.

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIFS(X!A:A, "John", X!B:B, "Smith")>0
```

Unless there's more to it that I didn't catch.

You can replace "John" and "Smith" with the addresses of the cells containing the names to search.

Comment: Perfect! I was unaware COUNTIFS would only return True if both names were on the same row, so I didn't even think to use it. 

Thank you!

Comment: @Necessarily yep, `COUNTIFS` takes "aligned" ranges and applies the criteria to each row "simultaneously" as logical "AND".